# Add tables to the database on cloudbees or run .sql file for database in cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I have an AppFuse struts 2 app. I am trying to deploy it on cloudbees. I have created a database and bound it with the DB but I am not sure how to add tables to the database on cloudbees. Is there a way I can run .sql script on database created in cloudbees? 
Also when I try to run the app using link it gives error Requested resource not available. I am guessing its because of lack of DB . Can anyone help me on adding tables and data to DB? and also execute the app smoothly on cloudbees?

Thanks a ton for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the tables and populate the data using different ways. You have [here](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/11/how-to-accesspopulate-cloudbees-mysql.html) an article which explains you how to do it.

From your application, using Spring, you can use something like this. You need to figure it out for other frameworks.

```
<!-- Database initializer. If any of the script fails, the initialization stops. -->
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.initLocation}"/>
    <jdbc:script location="${jdbc.dataLocation}"/>
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

If you plan to use a MySQL client, then you should take a look at [this](http://www.comtechies.com/2013/03/how-to-create-and-connect-cloudbees.html#.UbBACECpqvs), which explains it step by step.

Regarding how to deploy and to bind a Tomcat 7 app with your database, you can take a look at [this](http://developer-blog.cloudbees.com/2013/09/bind-your-java-application-to-your.html) blog post.

You can find info about all the containers we support [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer , I am going to try these.

Comment: mysqldump --user=b7ccefd559a35e --password='' --host=us-cdbr-cb-east-01.cleardb.net --port=3306 basicapp < basicappDBSchema.sql

Comment: Access denied for user 'b7ccefd559a35e'@'%' to database 'basicapp' when selecting the database. I am providing the correct password that I see on Database manager page for DB on cloudbees. I just didnt mention password here.

Comment: I get the same access denied error when I try to do the dump from mysqlworkbench. I can connect to the db though using mysqlworkbench but not import the data to the db

Comment: It could be you are behind a firewall. Feel free to open a support ticket. Difficult to diagnosis from here.

Comment: Got the issue resolved by changing the SQL db script. Thanks for your help.